# Measure length (in pixels) between multiple points on an image?

Tags: qgis, distance

I have a fairly high resolution map (jpg, not vector), with a known scale. How to measure the length in pixels between multiple points on an image? For a straight line it is simple, but how to do it when there are multiple points / no straight lines? Is there a simple GIS tool that could do such a thing?

*Example:*

This can be reduced to 9 legs to get the total length in pixels.

[image]

I currently use the measure tool in Gimp, which allows for a maximum of two legs only. This gets tedious quickly (write down the pixels, and then sum the total later), when there are a lot of curves in a road.

Browsing through this Stack, I found QGIS, and installed it. I can import the map as a raster layer, but from that point on I'm not sure what to do. Can I overlay the map with points/lines somehow, to get distances?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me; do you want to manually measure distances on a map or do you want to want to connect points with polylines and get their distances?

Comment: I have a "flat" map, containing roads and points of interest. Roads are not straight, so I'm looking for a way to measure distances in pixels, which I can convert back to miles. I'll try to rephrase the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Would the measure tool in QGIS suffice? "Ctrl + shfit + m". This allows you to manually measure your map in your map units.

Comment: @MarcM, Nice one. It certainly seems that it will do the trick, provided that it can be tamed into reflecting the correct scale.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something you will need to georeference your map to be able to measure distances in QGIS: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/georeferencing_basics.html

Comment: That is correct. I was not aware that the map is not georeferenced.

Comment: Thanks, yes sorry, I wasn't aware georeferencing is thing :-). Now following instructions from humperderp's link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your map is not georeferenced, you will have to do that first. @humperderp posted a good tutorial on that https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/georeferencing_basics.html.

After referencing, the distances can be measured manually in QGIS using the `measure tool` (Ctrl + shift +m )